# Unable to use TextBox after including MaterialDesignInXaml

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, material-design-in-xaml

I'm building a library (plugin for Revit). I have a `Window` in which I have included Material design successfully.

When I try adding `TextBox` control to this `Window`, I get the following error

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'
>   Inner Exception: NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Since I'm building a library, I don't have an App.xaml file, so I created a resource dictionary with the following content:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I include it to my `Window` using

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAsembly;component/MaterialDesign.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
```

As I said, using plain simple `TextBox` throw an exception, no styles, no anything

```xml
<TextBox />
```

All the other WPF controls that I've used so far work normally after including Material design in a window/page.

I have another `Window` in the same app where I already have `TextBox`. If I try including MaterialDesign to that `Window`, I get the same error; without MaterialDesing, `TextBox` works normally. If I include MaterialDesing and comment out the `TextBox`, the code works normally.

Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: Demo app that demonstrates the problem can be found [here](https://github.com/JovanovicMarija/TextBox-MaterialDesign-Revit).

Answer (score 0):

You must also provide the `XAML namespace` along with your `ResourceDictionary` declaration as shown below.

```cs
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score -1):

put this line to your main window tag 
 xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

Comment: I have it already. Also, i'm not using any control from this library atm.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your comment. I want to be using Material design, i'm just saying it's not the include statement that is causing the problem at the moment. I narrowed the problem to the use of `TextBox`, not any of the attributes that Material design implements.

Comment: Yes, please take a look at the EDIT part of the original question. I linked demo github repo.